# How to use GetX Navigation from a Page to detailPage

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Here is my problem, I want to retrieve data based on the list of data options provided from the API, when I click on the selected section, I hope I want to go to the detail page and display it according to the selected data. more or less I want to make a plot like this in the following example
[image]

I use API from randomapi :

> https://randomuser.me/api/?results=2

so please help me, this is the full code:

**Provider.dart**

```
class KonvensionalProvider extends GetConnect {
  Future<List<dynamic>> getUser() async {
    final response = await get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=2');
    if (response.status.hasError) {
      return Future.error(response.statusText!);
    } else {
      return response.body['results'];
    }
  }
}
```

**ProdukKonvesionalController.dart**

```
class ProdukKonvensionalController extends GetxController
    with StateMixin<List<dynamic>> {
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    KonvensionalProvider().getUser().then((value) {
      change(value, status: RxStatus.success());
    }, onError: (error) {
      change(null, status: RxStatus.error(error.toString()));
    });
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    // TODO: implement onClose
    super.onClose();
  }
}
```

**ProdukKonvensional.dart**

```
class ProdukKonvensionalPage extends GetView<ProdukKonvensionalController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Produk Konvensional'),
      ),
      body: controller.obx((data) => Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text(data[index]['name']['first']),
                        subtitle: Text(data[index]['name']['last']),
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage:
                              NetworkImage(data[index]['picture']['thumbnail']),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          Get.toNamed('/produkkonvensionaldetails');
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }))),
    );
  }
}
```

**ProdukKonvesionalDetail.dart**

```
class ProdukKonvensionalDetailPage extends GetView<ProdukKonvensionalController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.find();
    final _headerStyle = const TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xffffffff), fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
    final _contentStyleHeader = const TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xff999999), fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700);
    final _contentStyle = const TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xff999999), fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal);
    final _loremIpsum =
        '''Lorem ipsum is typically a corrupted version of 'De finibus bonorum et malor''';
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Detail Konvensional'),
      ),
      body: controller.obx((data) => Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Image.network(data[index]['picture']['large']),
                    Text(data[index]['name']['first'], style: TextStyle()),
                    Text(data[index]['name']['last']),
                    Accordion(
                        maxOpenSections: 2,
                        headerBackgroundColorOpened: Colors.white,
                        scaleWhenAnimating: true,
                        openAndCloseAnimation: true,
                        headerPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 7, horizontal: 15),
                        // sectionOpeningHapticFeedback: SectionHapticFeedback.heavy,
                        // sectionClosingHapticFeedback: SectionHapticFeedback.light,
                        children: [
                          AccordionSection(
                            leftIcon: const Icon(Icons.insights_rounded,
                                color: Colors.white),
                            contentBorderColor: const Color(0xffffffff),
                            headerBackgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
                            headerBackgroundColorOpened: Colors.blue[500],
                            header: Text(
                              'Deskripsi',
                              style: _headerStyle,
                            ),
                            content: Text("lorem Ipsum"),
                            contentHorizontalPadding: 20,
                            contentBorderWidth: 1,
                            // onOpenSection: () => print('onOpenSection ...'),
                            // onCloseSection: () => print('onCloseSection ...'),
                          ),
                          AccordionSection(
                            leftIcon: const Icon(Icons.insights_rounded,
                                color: Colors.white),
                            contentBorderColor: const Color(0xffffffff),
                            headerBackgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
                            headerBackgroundColorOpened: Colors.blue[500],
                            header: Text(
                              'Syarat',
                              style: _headerStyle,
                            ),
                            content: Text("lorem Ipsum"),
                            contentHorizontalPadding: 20,
                            contentBorderWidth: 1,
                          ),
                          AccordionSection(
                            leftIcon: const Icon(Icons.insights_rounded,
                                color: Colors.white),
                            contentBorderColor: const Color(0xffffffff),
                            headerBackgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
                            headerBackgroundColorOpened: Colors.blue[500],
                            header: Text(
                              'Ketentuan',
                              style: _headerStyle,
                            ),
                            content: Text("lorem Ipsum"),
                            contentHorizontalPadding: 20,
                            contentBorderWidth: 1,
                          ),
                          AccordionSection(
                            leftIcon: const Icon(Icons.insights_rounded,
                                color: Colors.white),
                            contentBorderColor: const Color(0xffffffff),
                            headerBackgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
                            headerBackgroundColorOpened: Colors.blue[500],
                            header: Text(
                              'Fasilitas dan Manfaat',
                              style: _headerStyle,
                            ),
                            content: Text("lorem Ipsum"),
                            contentHorizontalPadding: 20,
                            contentBorderWidth: 1,
                          ),
                          AccordionSection(
                            leftIcon: const Icon(Icons.insights_rounded,
                                color: Colors.white),
                            contentBorderColor: const Color(0xffffffff),
                            headerBackgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
                            headerBackgroundColorOpened: Colors.blue[500],
                            header: Text(
                              'SK/SE',
                              style: _headerStyle,
                            ),
                            content: Text("lorem Ipsum"),
                            contentHorizontalPadding: 20,
                            contentBorderWidth: 1,
                          ),
                        ]),
                  ],
                );
              }))),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help friends, this is my study assignment

Answer (score 0):

**Step: 1** : Sending data

```
Get.to(Second(), arguments: [data[index]['name']['first']]);
```

**Step: 2** : Get data From first screen

```
var data = Get.arguments;


 onTap: () {
Get.toNamed('/produkkonvensionaldetails', arguments: ["First data", "Second data"]); },
```

Comment: i have error when click to detailpage ""dynamic" not found. You need to call "Get.put(dynamic())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>dynamic())"" @MohitJadav86